# Last record gets duplicated

Tags: mysql

I'm declaring a cursor and insert records from a table. After insertion i observed last record is getting duplicated.

```
DECLARE complete INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE empCursor CURSOR FOR select name from employee;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET complete = 1;
OPEN empCursor;
        REPEAT
            FETCH empCursor INTO name;
            INSERT INTO emp_dump(NAME);
        UNTIL complete=1 END REPEAT;
CLOSE empCursor;
```

What is going wrong with the above procedure? Why it duplicates the last record?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `FETCH empCursor INTO name` will not return a result, you set complete=1.

But afterwards you insert a RECORD with `INSERT INTO emp_dump(NAME)` without checking if complete was set to 1. Since the previous fetch didn't return a result, NAME has still the old value and will be inserted twice.

Comment: What is the fix has to be made? can you put some code to see whether it works

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, the fix is to check the value of complete before you INSERT.